# Centering window python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, numbers, window

Ive recently started using tkinter in python, and I was having trouble centering the window. I tried all the tips on this website, but whenever I try them, the window is like a line in the middle of the screen. I have widgets already on it, and it works fine without the centering, but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve my problem.
This is what I have been trying so far.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Password")
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

w = mainframe.winfo_width()
h = mainframe.winfo_height()
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have found and fixed the problem. Piggybacking off of OregonTrail's solution, i found that if the window is the right size and you just want to change the location, then you can easily instead of setting the root's size, you can just move the window to the center.

```
w = root.winfo_reqwidth()
h = root.winfo_reqheight()
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y)) ## this part allows you to only change the location
```

I think that this answer isn't exactly in the center, probably off by a little since h was returning 200 when it should be less, but it looks to be at the center and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()`, because the window does not have a height or width at the time that you call `winfo_height()` and `winfo_width()`.

An example program:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="white")

l1 = ttk.Label(text="This is the best label in the world", style="BW.TLabel")
l1.pack()

w = l1.winfo_reqwidth()
h = l1.winfo_reqheight()
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
print(w, h, x, y)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But for this, i need to use a widget to configure the req_height() and req_width(), but my code uses many widgets (the original post included only the parts i thought significant).

Comment: And if I use the root, the height is too large.

Comment: I am using dual monitors on a laptop and using this code the window is kinda centered between the two screens.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully someone will find use of this code, basically this is a solution you can use to center a TopLevel window relative to master (parent) window.
Probably not the cleanest solution, but it will get the work done.

```
from Tkinter import *

class PasswordDialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.title("Password")

        self.label_info = Label(self, text="You need to enter your password", pady=10)
        self.label_info.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ew")
        self.label_pw = Label(self, text="Enter password:", pady=10)
        self.label_pw.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 2), sticky="e")
        self.entry = Entry(self, show="*")
        self.entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.store_pass_event)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(2,20), sticky="w")
        self.button = Button(self, command=self.store_pass, text="Log in")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.update()

        size = tuple(int(_) for _ in self.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        parent_offset = tuple(int(_) for _ in self.master.geometry().split('x')[1].split('+'))

        parent_width = self.master.winfo_width()
        parent_height = self.master.winfo_height()
        
        x = parent_width//2 - size[0]//2 + parent_offset[1]
        y = parent_height//2 - size[1]//2 + parent_offset[2]

        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

    def store_pass_event(self, event):
        self.store_pass()

    def store_pass(self):
        self.master.password = self.entry.get()
        self.destroy()
```